# MySQL getting value from two tables with condition

Tags: mysql

I think I have done as much as I know for this step

Having hard time to convert the statement below into Query.

---

select house_code from house_info

where house_info.house_code does not exists in family_info

---

The `house_code` is primary key and unique in `house_info` table.
However, `house_code` in `family_info` is not unique nor primary key (multiple number of same `house_code` exists)

I am trying to get `house_code` values that does not exist in `family_info` in comparison to `house_info`

ex)  house_code in house_info (1,2,3,4,5) and house_code in family_info(1,1,2,2,3)

Result: 4, 5

I have tried to use Inner Join, If not exist and many other queries but it doesn't seem to work as I want

Ive also tried

```
 SELECT a.house_code FROM house_info a, family_info b WHERE a.house_code!=b.house_code;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT house_code FROM house_info 
WHERE house_code NOT IN (SELECT house_code FROM family_info)
```

Following your example:

```
SELECT house_code FROM house_info
```

==> (1,2,3,4,5) = A

```
(SELECT house_code FROM family_info)
```

==> (1,1,2,2,3) = B

```
A NOT IN B
```

==> (4,5)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get there

```
select house_code from house_info
where house_info.house_code not in (select house_code from family_info)
```

The `not in` means "The value isn't part of this set of values" and the nested select provides the set of values.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using unilateral join:

```
select 
    h.house_code
from 
    house_info as h
    left join family_info as f on h.house_code = f.house_code
where
    f.house_code is null
```